# Displaying facebook information via Google Maps

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, google-maps, facebook-graph-api

ok I am trying to create a web app that uses gmaps and fb friend list together.  The first step is being able to display current location on a google maps which would should name and picture of person signed in.  I have it currently where you can only view the map if you are signed into facebook, but except for that, I am unable to get the 2 to interact.

my maps.js file looks like this:

```
"use strict";
var map;
var markers = []

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
   var center = map.getCenter();
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
   map.setCenter(center); 
  });

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);


      socket.emit('marker', {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      });

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<%= user.displayName %>'
      });

      var markerPos = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        title: '<%= user.displayName %>'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(markerPos, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,markerPos);
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// Add a marker to the map 
function addMarker(location, text) {
    text = text || '';

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(text); 
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    return marker;
}
```

The server file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express')
var passport = require('passport')
var util = require('util')
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
var logger = require('morgan')
var session = require('express-session')
var sessionStore = require('sessionstore');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var markers = [];
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var passportStrategy = require('../utils/passport-strategy');

var FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "";
var FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = "";

passport.use(passportStrategy.facebook);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});

var sessionData = session({
  store: sessionStore.createSessionStore(),
  secret: "your_secret",
  cookie: { maxAge: 2628000000 },
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
});

io.use(function(socket, next){
  sessionData(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    process.nextTick(function () {

      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));




var app = express();

  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(sessionData);
  app.use(logger());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(bodyParser());
  app.use(methodOverride());
  app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', { user: req.user });
});


app.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'),
  function(req, res){
  });


app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/mapjs', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/map.js', { user: req.user });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('marker', function(data) {
      data.socketId = socket.id;

      markers[socket.id] = data;


  console.log('marker latitude: ' + data.lat + ', marker longitude:' + data.lng);
    socket.broadcast.emit('show-marker', data);
    });

});

app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('five minute catch up is on port 3000');
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login')
}

module.exports = server;
```

the index.ejs looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Five Minute Catchup</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/main.css">
<!--    Internal map style (cant remove)-->
      <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 90%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
<!--   Public API  -->
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
  </head>

  <body>



  <% if(!user) { %>
  <div class="header">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">



              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Five Minute Catchup</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/account">Account</a></li>
                <a href="/auth/facebook"><img src="login-with-facebook.png" width="154" height="22"></a>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h2>Welcome! Please log in.</h2>

      <% } else { %>

        <div class="header">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>

              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Five Minute Catchup</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/account">Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <h2>Hello, <%= user.displayName %></h2>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      <% } %>




    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the Five Minute Catchup team</p>
      </div>
    </div>






        // <!-- <script src="public/map.js"></script> -->

        <!-- socket scripts -->
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
      <script src="/mapjs"></script>
      <script>
        var socket = io();
        //Listen for other users markers
        socket.on('show-marker', function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat,
                                         data.lng);
          addMarker(loc, data.socketId);
        });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

sorry for having to copy and paste the entire file, I didnt want to miss out some code that could be relevant!

Any help getting the fb name and image url inside of the google maps info window would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom makers and create a function that calls the facebook details.
see this demo on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/DVKEj/

```
var data = [{
profileImage:"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d735414fa8687e8874783702f6c96fa6?
s=90&d=identicon&r=PG"

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
new CustomMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].pos[0],data[i].pos[1]), map,   
data[i].profileImage)
}
```

Comment: but how do I make it so the infowindow shows like user.name?